# Change linespacing on a single row of a table

Tags: tables, spacing, line-spacing

I'd like to change the linespacing for a single row of a table. My whole document uses `\linespread{1.3}` but on this table it seems too much. Actually, I like it in all rows except the first. I figured out that by including `\usepackage{setspace}` in my documents it makes the linespread of tables and floats equal to 1 without changing the text of my documents. I still don't like this though. I want `linespread{1}` for the first row and `linespread{1.3}` for the other rows and the rest of the document.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pbox}
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{center}       
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc} 
    \hline\hline
       Appliance  & \pbox{2cm}{\centering Max power demand (watts)} & \pbox{2cm}{\centering On power threshold (watts)} & \pbox{2cm}{\centering Min. on duration (secs)} & \pbox{2cm}{\centering Min. off duration (secs)}   \\
       \hline
       A & 3100 & 2000 & 12 & 0 \\
       B & 300 & 50 & 60 & 12 \\
       C & 2500 & 20 & 1800 & 160 \\
       D & 3000 & 200 & 12 & 30 \\
       E & 2500 & 10 & 1800 & 1800 \\
           \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can always manipulate the distances between lines by replacing `\\ ` by `\\[2pt]` or any other distance instead of `2pt`.

Comment: Or with `booktabs`' `\addlinespace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ad hoc fix: set `\linespread{1}` where needed. I kicked out the `pbox` package, loaded `array` instead, and defined a new column type which does the same as your `\pbox`es but with a different `\linespread`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\linespread{1.3}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\linespread{1}\selectfont\centering}m{2cm}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{center}       
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc} 
    \hline\hline
       Appliance  & \multicolumn{1}{M}{Max power demand (watts)} & 
       \multicolumn{1}{M}{On power threshold (watts)} & 
       \multicolumn{1}{M}{Min. on duration (secs)} & 
       \multicolumn{1}{M}{Min. off duration (secs)}   
       \\
       \hline
       A & 3100 & 2000 & 12 & 0 \\
       B & 300 & 50 & 60 & 12 \\
       C & 2500 & 20 & 1800 & 160 \\
       D & 3000 & 200 & 12 & 30 \\
       E & 2500 & 10 & 1800 & 1800 \\
           \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I could do that if my document was only the table but it will change linespacing in the whole document. It's a big one with a lot of text which I want to stay to `linespread{1.3}`. Also, is it possible to add a bit more space between the letters of the first row and the double line at the top?

Comment: @itroulli Fair enough. I tried to give a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `makecell` package to adjust row spacing, and `booktabs` for variable thickness rules and some vertical padding around them. Also, don't use the `center` environment for  tables – it adds unwanted vertical spacing. Use `\centering` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
   \renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule\specialrule{0.5pt}{1.5pt}{\belowrulesep}
       Appliance & \makecell{Max power \\ demand \\ (watts)} & \makecell{On power \\ threshold \\ (watts)} & \makecell{Min. on \\ duration \\ (secs)} & \makecell{Min. off \\ duration \\ (secs)} \\
       \cmidrule[0.5pt](lr){1-5}
       A & 3100 & 2000 & 12 & 0 \\
       B & 300 & 50 & 60 & 12 \\
       C & 2500 & 20 & 1800 & 160 \\
       D & 3000 & 200 & 12 & 30 \\
       E & 2500 & 10 & 1800 & 1800 \\
           \specialrule{0.5pt}{\aboverulesep}{1.5pt}\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

To get a wider table, you can make two-line column heads:

```
 \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule\specialrule{0.5pt}{1.5pt}{\belowrulesep}
       Appliance & \makecell{Max power \\ demand (watts)} & \makecell{On power \\ threshold (watts)} & \makecell{Min. on \\ duration (secs)} & \makecell{Min. off \\ duration (secs)} \\
       \cmidrule[0.5pt](lr){1-5}
       A & 3100 & 2000 & 12 & 0 \\
       B & 300 & 50 & 60 & 12 \\
       C & 2500 & 20 & 1800 & 160 \\
       D & 3000 & 200 & 12 & 30 \\
       E & 2500 & 10 & 1800 & 1800 \\
           \specialrule{0.5pt}{\aboverulesep}{1.5pt}\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you modify it so it's a bit wider? I mean the whole table. Also, as I'm new here, what's the best way to post an image of the outcome of some code here? Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Personally I take a screenshot of a zone of the result, and post with the icon  looking like a mountain in the toolbar of the edit window.

Comment: @itroulli: I've added a variant with only two lines in the column heads. Is that more  like what you want?