# Reduce spacing inside cell, vertical and horizontal positioning of figure & defining some text in preamble

Tags: tikz-styles, line-spacing, variable

I want to make a template document (with custom margins, font sizes, header, footer etc...).

I have specified only footer on first page and header on all other pages, margins, text width, text height, header height, page borders.. that's all as I want.

I have marked with numbers in following pictures things I want to change.

1. I want multiline text like represented, but I want to reduce line spacing. Code:

   ```
   %%begin page borders
   \SetBgOpacity{100.0}    %% Select opacity
   \SetBgScale{1}          %% Select scale factor of logo
   \SetBgAngle{0}          %% Select rotation of logo
   \SetBgColor{black}      %% Select color
   \SetBgContents{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
   \node[anchor=north] at ($(current page.north west)+(1.5cm,-1cm)$) 
   {\rotatebox{90}{\makecell[r]{\scriptsize\selectfont Reproduction or any 
   use not conformity with the intended\\

   \scriptsize\selectfont application is not permissible.}}};
   \node[anchor=south] at ($(current page.south west)+(1.5cm,1cm)$) 
   {\rotatebox{90}{\makecell[l]{\scriptsize\selectfont Nachdruck oder 
   Verwendung, die nicht der beabsichtigten\\

   \scriptsize\selectfont Anwendung entspricht, ist nicht zulässig.}}};

   \end{tikzpicture}
   }
   %%end page borders
   ```
2. I didn't finish my table on the left, but I know how to add more rows it's not a problem. My question is how to fix row height or how to remove or reduce additional text spacing inside cell? I dont want to resize table because I want my width to be the same.
3. How to position figure vertically and horizontally centered inside cell? Is there any option like [anchor=center]?
4. On first page footer and all other pages header I have same attribute in header and footer for example Project. Can I define in preamble for example: project=My first project in LaTeX; and then in header and footer in specific cell when i write project, my output will be My first project in LaTeX.

Should I implement KOMA-scripts, is there any advantages in my case?
With KOMA-scripts can I specify exactly which font size I want to use for example \fontsize{5} Some random text. Iam asking this because of easier changing font size inside tables. :)

my complete code:

```
%%begin preamble
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{url}
%%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper}                                                     
%%odabir veličine papira
\geometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm}}       
%%podešavanje margina
\geometry{includehead=true,headheight=3.5cm,headsep=1cm}                     
%%podešavanje headinga
\geometry{includefoot=false}                                                 
%%podešavanje footinga

\setlength{\parindent}{0.95cm}      %%paragraf uvodni razmak

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  %%delete default header line

\newcommand{\thenextpage}{\number\numexpr\thepage+1\relax}

%%begin page borders
\SetBgOpacity{100.0}    %% Select opacity
\SetBgScale{1}          %% Select scale factor of logo
\SetBgAngle{0}          %% Select rotation of logo
\SetBgColor{black}      %% Select color
\SetBgContents{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [line width=1pt,rounded corners=0pt]
($ (current page.north west) + (2.5cm,-1cm) $)
rectangle
($ (current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $);

\draw [line width=1.5pt]
($ (current page.north west) + (2.5cm,-14.85cm) $) -- ($ (current page.north 
west) + (1cm,-14.85cm) $);

\node[anchor=north] at ($(current page.north west)+(1.5cm,-1cm)$) 
{\rotatebox{90}{\makecell[r]{\scriptsize\selectfont Reproduction or any use 
not conformity with the intended\\

\scriptsize\selectfont application is not permissible.}}};
\node[anchor=north] at ($(current page.south west)+(1.5cm,1cm)$) 
{\rotatebox{90}{\makecell[l]{\scriptsize\selectfont Nachdruck oder 
Verwendung, die nicht der beabsichtigten\\

\scriptsize\selectfont Anwendung entspricht, ist nicht zulässig.}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
}
%%end page borders

%%begin firstpage footer
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyhf{}                      %% clear default for head and foot
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.south west)+ (2.5cm,1cm)$) {
        \begin{tabular}{@{}p{5.45cm}@{}|@{}p{3.5cm}@{}|@{}p{6cm}@{}|@{}p{1.5cm}@{}@{}p{1cm}@{}}
        \hline
        \scriptsize Projekt:                                 & \scriptsize Vertrag Nr.:                             & \scriptsize Dokument Nr.:                            & \scriptsize Seite:                                   & \textbf{\thepage} \bigstrut\\
        \cline{4-5}    \centering\textbf{\footnotesize Project} &                                          & \centering\textbf{\footnotesize Document number}       & \scriptsize Nächste Seite:                           & \textbf{\footnotesize \thenextpage} \bigstrut\\
        \hline
        \scriptsize Titel:                                   & \scriptsize Format:                                  & \scriptsize Rahmen:                                  & \scriptsize Gesamte Seite:                              & \textbf{\footnotesize \pageref*{LastPage}} \bigstrut[t]\\
        \centering\textbf{\footnotesize Title} & \centering\textbf{\footnotesize Format}                              & \centering\textbf{\footnotesize 1:1}                             &                                          &  \bigstrut[b]\\
        \end{tabular}%
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
%%end firstpage footer

%%begin default header for all pages; except first page style
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyfoot[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all footers
\fancyhf{}                      %% clear default for head and foot
\fancyhead[C]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north west)+(2.5cm,-1cm)$) {
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{4cm}@{}|@{}p{6.45cm}@{}|@{}p{6cm}@{}@{}p{1cm}@{}}
    \multirow{4}[6]{*}{\includegraphics[valign=m,scale=0.25]{\cenlogo.png}}                 & \scriptsize Projekt:                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\scriptsize Dokument Nr.:}       & \scriptsize Rev.: \bigstrut[t]\\
    & \centering\textbf{\footnotesize Project} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{\footnotesize Document number}} &  \textbf{\footnotesize A} \bigstrut[b]\\
    \cline{2-4}                                             & \scriptsize Titel:                                   & \scriptsize Seite:                                   & \textbf{\footnotesize \thepage} \bigstrut\\
    \cline{3-4}                                             & \centering\textbf{\footnotesize Title} & \scriptsize Seitenzahl:                              & \textbf{\footnotesize \pageref*{LastPage}} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%%end default header for all pages; except first page style

%%end preamble
\begin{document}
%%titlepage begin

\thispagestyle{firstpage}       %%\fancypagestyle{firstpage}

%%begin podešavanje margina, headinga i footinga za početnu stranicu
\newgeometry{bindingoffset=1.5cm,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={1cm,1cm},
            includehead=false,
            includefoot=true,footskip=2cm
}
%%end podešavanje margina, headinga i footinga za početnu stranicu

\vspace*{6cm}                   %%6cm vertical offset
\begin{center}
    \Huge Some random text\\
    \large Some random text\\~\\
    \Huge Some random text\\
    \large Some random text
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}                 %%fill page with empty space

%%titlepage end

\newpage
\restoregeometry                %%restore to default header for all pages; except first page style
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-8]

\newpage

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-8]

\newpage

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[1-8]


\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!
Best regards

[image]

Comment: Regarding 3): You can use `>{\centering}p{4cm}` instead of `p{4cm}` in oder to also horizontally center the image in the cell. Regarding 1): You could use `\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}}` as described here: [Change linespacing on a single row of a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419569/134144)